# How to apply Artifactory Permission Target to pip, and other non-human-predicatable/readable repo's?

Tags: artifactory

To make Artifactory as self-service as possible for our users, giving permissions to users to deploy to parts of repositories using their personal or team accounts, I'm trying to figure out how to configure this.
For readable directory structure based repositories like anything in the java world, the `Permission Targets` work perfectly (https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Managing+Permissions). But I can't find any docs on how to use this for non-human-predicatable/readable directory structures, like PIP, or the flat directory structure, like NPM.

In the java world, repositories have a nicely structured tree like:

```
~/.m2/repository$ tree org/ | head -20
org/
├── antlr
│   ├── antlr4-master
│   │   └── 4.7.1
│   │       ├── antlr4-master-4.7.1.pom
│   │       ├── antlr4-master-4.7.1.pom.sha1
│   │       └── _remote.repositories
│   └── antlr4-runtime
│       └── 4.7.1
│           ├── antlr4-runtime-4.7.1.jar
│           ├── antlr4-runtime-4.7.1.jar.sha1
│           ├── antlr4-runtime-4.7.1.pom
│           ├── antlr4-runtime-4.7.1.pom.sha1
│           └── _remote.repositories
├── apache
│   ├── ant
│   │   ├── ant
│   │   │   ├── 1.10.1
│   │   │   │   ├── ant-1.10.1.jar
│   │   │   │   ├── ant-1.10.1.jar.sha1
```

For example, to give `teamantl` permission to only read, annotate, and write to `org/antlr/antlr4-master/**`, the following json can be PUT to Artifactory REST API (`PUT /api/security/permissions/{permissionTargetName}`)

```
{
  "includesPattern": "org/antlr/antlr4-master/**",
  "repositories": [
    "libs-release-local",
    "libs-snapshot-local"
  ],
  "principals": {
    "groups" : {
      "teamantl": ["r","n","w"]
    }
  }
}
```

But for example a pip repo is completely hashed:
[image: Hashed PIP repo tree]
Which is completely useless in the permission target "includesPattern".

How should this (Permission Targets) work for repo's like PIP, and NPM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot shows a *virtual* PyPI repo, which is generated and thus hash-structured.

Normally, these are backed by *physical* repos, filled using `twine upload` and thus having a `‹pkg›/‹version›/‹file›` structure – i.e. perfectly usable as permission targets with package granularity.